# UIImageView with subview like Facebook messenger

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I need to draw a UIImageView like Facebook messenger (Facebook profile plus messenger logo).
I need a circular UIImageView with a subview (messenger logo) not clipped.

Someone has an idea?

My code:

```
class CustomImageView : UIImageView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius     = frame.size.height/2
        self.layer.masksToBounds    = false
        self.clipsToBounds          = true
        self.contentMode            = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let facebookProfil = CustomImageView(....)
let messengerLogo = CustomImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15 , height: 15))
facebookProfil(messengerLogo)
```

i've got this

[image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgEQF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

  let logoImageView = UIImageView()

  convenience init(image: UIImage, logo: UIImage) {
    self.init(image: image)
    self.logoImageView.image = logo
    self.clipsToBounds          = true
    self.contentMode            = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    logoImageView.clipsToBounds = true
  }

  override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius     = frame.size.height/2
    logoImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: self.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    self.superview?.addSubview(logoImageView)
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work with corner radius on custom image view